# Тире или запятые при причастном обороте?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, причастный-оборот, поэзия

Можно ли вариант 1 вместо 2 использовать? Это из песни «Единственный дом».

1. > Среди городов — шумящих и ночью и днём — и тысяч домов — нам нужен единственный дом.
2. > Среди городов, шумящих и ночью и днём, и тысяч домов — нам нужен единственный дом.

Comment: Вреди — это что значит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

❶. Имеется много вариантов пунктуационного оформления этих песенных строк.
Часто встречается такое:
*Среди городов — шумящих и ночью, и днём, и тысяч домов — нам нужен единственный дом...*
Оно, считаю, противоречит смыслу (среди городов нам нужен дом).

❷. У [автора](https://vokrugknig.blogspot.com/2020/05/blog-post_72.html) стихов, Д. Рубина, такие "расстановки":
*Среди городов,

Шумящих и ночью, и днём,

И тысяч домов

Нам нужен единственный дом...*

❸. *Среди городов — шумящих и ночью и днём — и тысяч домов — нам нужен единственный дом...*
Можно ли так написать? Думаю, что ***не нужно***.
Получаются три тире подряд: два авторских со вставкой (причастный оборот *шумящих и ночью и днём*) и авторское интонационное. Слишком много "авторства", которое сложно воспринимается.

❹. Именно для [песенного исполнения](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjVLsAas-sw) (можно послушать) я бы использовала пунктуацию, обозначенную у вас в вопросе номером два:
*Среди городов, шумящих и ночью и днём, и тысяч домов — нам нужен единственный дом...*

❺. Предложение приведено не полностью, поэтому при цитировании в конце необходимо ставить многоточие.

Comment: По сути. Три тире плохо смотрятся. Нсли бы я причастный оборот использовал как пояснение, то я бы убрал третье тире. Больно уж плохо они смотрятся, когда их три...

Comment: Я так и написала.